# Rails 3: Unknown attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rake-task

I'm wondering if someone could give me some hints as to why I'm getting an unknown attribute error when trying to create instances of a model I have created (Card).  Here is a stripped down version of the model class and the rake task where I am getting the error.

Card class:

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :some_other_model
  belongs_to :some_other_other_model
  attr_accessible :attr1, :attr2, :attr3, :attr4,...,:card_type,...
end
```

rake task:

```
task :import_cards => :environment do
  # connect to database
  conn = Mysql2::Client.new(yadda yadda yadda)

  results = conn.query("SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4,..., card_type, ... FROM that_table;")

  results.each{|row|; Card.create(:attr1 => row['attr1'], :attr2 => row['attr2'], :attr3 => row['attr3'], :attr4 => row['attr4'],..., :card_type => row['card_type'],...);}

  conn.close()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had another issue.  My db was out of date.  Column name had been changed from type to card_type.